# Objective-C to Swift Equivilant

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm trying to figure out how to write this block method in swift. I can't seem to get the closure syntax right:

```
[self.colorPickerView setDidChangeColorBlock:^(UIColor *color){
        self.selectedColor.backgroundColor = self.colorPickerView.color;
}];
```

Thanks in advance!

What i tried:

```
self.colorPickerView.didChangeColorBlock({
    (color: UIColor) in self.selectedColorView.backgroundColor = self.colorPickerView.color
})
```

Final Solution:

```
self.colorPickerView.didChangeColorBlock = {
            (color: UIColor!) in
            self.selectedColorView.backgroundColor = color
        }
```

Comment: I tried what serejahh suggested, and the above. The error i'm getting is: (UIColor) -> (UIColor) -> $T3 is not convertible to 'UIColor'

Comment: btw you should use the color provided in the callback block instead of `self.colorPickerView.color` and weakify/strongify self as long as you don;t want a retain loop (the block retains self and self retains the block).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use

```
self.colorPickerView.didChangeColorBlock = { ...
```

instead of

```
self.colorPickerView.didChangeColorBlock({ ...
```

Since `didChangeColorBlock` is a property, not a method.